# Angular 2 calling a child component method from the parent

Tags: angular, methods, parent-child

I have tried to use different methods suggested in StackOverflow but I cannot make the following work.

I have a nested ChildComponent into a ParentComponent.

Here the HTML of the parent:

```
<div> ... <div>

<span *ngIf="value" class="option-button cursor-pointer" [attr.modelURL]="value"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation();getParts(assemblyLibrary)">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
</span>

<child-component></child-component>
```

Obviously, I have imported the child component into the parent one:

```
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared'; //child declaration is inside here
```

in the parent component, I am implementing the following code:

```
import { child-component } from '../../../child-component';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    templateUrl: './parent-component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    ...

    @ViewChild('ChildComponent') childComponent;

    openDialog(filesToLoad) {
        this.childComponent.openDialog(filesToLoad);
    }

    getParts(value) {
        this.filesToLoad = [];

        ... code to populate files to load

        this.openDialog(this.filesToLoad);
    }}
}
```

When I call the getParts(value) by clicking on the  declared in my HTML I get the following error:

> VM21157:55 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'openDialog' of undefined

what is wrong with this approach suggested by many users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parent html should be like:

```
<child-component #childComponent></child-component>
```

then you can access this element with `@ViewChild`

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    ...

    @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent;
```

Right now your `@ViewChild('ChildComponent') childComponent;` selects nothing since you don't have a `#ChildComponent` selector in your template.

Comment: dear echonax, there must be something else. I have modified the code as suggested and still giving the same error.

Comment: @Dino can you update your question with the way you edited it? Be careful on upper/lower-case words.

Comment: You are a star echonax, it was indeed an UPPER/LOWER CASE ISSUE and I went over the code millions of times...

Comment: @Dino haha, glad you figured it out.