# Angular 2/4: Can't update child component view

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to update the value of str which I used in the view of child component from the parent component, by calling the function change() of child component
here is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>parent</h1>
    <button (click)="changeChild()">change child</button>
    <app-child></app-child>
    `,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(private cc:ChildComponent) {}

   changeChild(){
      this.cc.change();
   }

}
```

and the child component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-child',
   template: `
       <p>{{str}}</p>
   `,
   styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
 })
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

   private str;

   constructor() { 
      this.str = 'initial'
   }

   change(){
      this.str = 'changed'
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     }

 }
```

but the value str in the view never updated to "changed".

please Any help because I am new in Angular 4 ??

Comment: Check out https://angular.io/tutorial to get a basic understanding of how angular works :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 calling a child component method from the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078725/angular-2-calling-a-child-component-method-from-the-parent)

Comment: You can access the child component use to Viewchild. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: where did you saw that you can manipulate a child component like that?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I didn't, please suggest me a way to reach my goal

Comment: @mahmoudabdellatif https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use @ViewChild to get reference of child component

```
in Parent component


        import {ChildComponent} from 'child.component.ts' 

export class ParentComponent{
------

@ViewChild(ChildComponent)
private child:ChildComponent

---

changeChild(){
this.child.change()
}
}
```